# Regular expression to test if a filename ends with a suffix: wrong result

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using this function to

```
    exportAsIndustryFormats('phz', 'file:///home/m3/Documents/exported/layers6.phz');

    function exportAsIndustryFormats(suffixStr, file) {
        var endsWithSuffix = new RegExp('/\.' + suffixStr + '$/')
        var doesEnd = endsWithSuffix.test(file) // This test result is wrong!?
        console.log("Does file ends with suffix ===", doesEnd)

        if(doesEnd) {
        } else {
            file += '.' + suffixStr
        }

        console.log("Suffix ===", suffixStr)
        console.log("file ===", file)

        // ...
    }
```

My app logs this which is *not* expected:

```
// Input file URL:
qml: fileUrl === file:///home/m3/Documents/exported/layers6.phz
qml: Does file ends with suffix === false
qml: Suffix === phz
// Adds an extra suffix, since it thinks the suffix is NOT there:
qml: file === file:///home/m3/Documents/exported/layers6.phz.phz
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the code. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should define the new Regex with this in your case `new RegExp('.' + suffixStr + '$')`. `new Regex` will generate the rest for you.

And second, you can check the last part of your input string by slicing the original string by the length of your target string like this:

```
var doesEnd = endsWithSuffix.test(file.slice(-(suffixStr.length + 1)));
```

The final code:

```js
    exportAsIndustryFormats('phz', 'file:///home/m3/Documents/exported/layers6.phz');

    function exportAsIndustryFormats(suffixStr, file) {
        var endsWithSuffix = new RegExp('.' + suffixStr + '$')
        var doesEnd = endsWithSuffix.test(file.slice(-(suffixStr.length + 1))); // This test result is wrong!?
        console.log("Does file ends with suffix ===", doesEnd)

        if(doesEnd) {
        } else {
            file += '.' + suffixStr
        }

        console.log("Suffix ===", suffixStr)
        console.log("file ===", file)

        // ...
    }
```